# Change listbox selected item foreground in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox, selecteditem

I have the following listbox:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,10">
                                <TextBlock 
                                    Foreground="Black"
                                    Text="{Binding name}"/>
                                <TextBlock
                                    Foreground="Black"
                                    Text=": "
                                    Visibility="{Binding 
                                        Path=name, 
                                        Converter={StaticResource ServiceOtherConverter}}"/>
                                <TextBlock 
                                    Foreground="Black"
                                    Text="{Binding amount}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding 
                                        Path=name, 
                                        Converter={StaticResource ServiceOtherConverter}}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

And my app has a white background, so I'd like to set the list items foreground to black. But when I select an item, its foreground doesn't change, as it does whith the default foreground.

How can I change the list items foreground to black but still have the selected foreground different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the Foreground in the Selected VisualState at the style template level for the ListBox Item. For reference you might peek at the msdn doc for [ListBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Expression Blend makes it pretty painless. Just right-click your item and choose "Edit Additional Templates" and choose the Item template. Then from the States tab, choose the Selected State and change the foreground color. Or you could just do it directly in the template code. Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean "right-click your item"? I can right click the listbox in "Objects and Timeline" but not an item.

Comment: @softarn - Something like this should help you out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/dd334538.aspx